# Shorthand with else if

Tags: javascript

How do I write shorthand for else if statements?

```
if (showvar == "instock"){
   //show available
} else if (showvar == "final3"){
  //show only 3 available
} else {
  //show Not available
}
```

I know to write when there's only `if` and `else`. But How do I write this when there's an `else if` statement?

```
(showvar == "instock")? //show available : //show Not available
```

Comment: Can you add complete code instead of just `show available`... `showvar === 'instock' ? 'show available' : (showvar === 'final3' ? 'show 3 available' : 'Not available');`

Comment: `(showvar == "instock")? //show available : (showvar == "final3" ? //show only 3 available : //show Not available )`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You simply nest the `else if`s on the `false` side of `:`; `else` clauses are simply `false` as well. Like so...

```
(showvar == "instock") 
    ? show available 
    : ((showvar == "final3") 
        ? show only 3 available 
        : show Not available);
```

Comment: Though this will work , do you recommend doing this?

Comment: @DecentGradient, it's been a long time but I was brought back here due to a recent downvote. No, I don't usually do this.